# Accessing ViewHelper from another ViewHelper specifically FlashMessenger

Tags: zend-framework, view-helpers

So I created a view helper to specialize/simplify some of the functionality of the Flash Messenger helper.

I have been looking around a lot and saw that you should be able to access the FlashMessenger helper through code like this:

$this->view->_helper->flashMessenger->getMessages();

This won't work for me. I can access view but not anything under _helper. My helper class does extend  Zend_View_Helper_Abstract. Do you have to explicitly pass in the view from the view script?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `$_helper` property of Zend_Controller_Action stores an instance of the Zend_Controller_Action_HelperBroker, so instead of passing it from the view to your helper, you can get an instance of the HelperBroker and then get the FlashMessenger object from there.

```
// inside your view helper
$messenger = Zend_Controller_Action_HelperBroker::getStaticHelper('FlashMessenger');
```

Now you have access to the Flash Messenger from within your view helper.  You can do the same from anywhere in the application to get a reference to any Action Helpers.

Also note, if the helper has not yet been created, calling `getStaticHelper` will initialize it for you.

See [Action Helpers - The Helper Broker](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.controller.actionhelpers.html#zend.controller.actionhelper.broker) for more information.

Comment: Awesome, what a perfect answer. I appreciate it.